# Has Anyone Ever Tried Modelling a Battery Cover?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I recently inherited my late great grandmother's Sharp WQ-CD120 boombox from 1995.

Everything appears to be fine except it's missing the battery cover. I can't find anyone selling them online so I thought I'd model one in Blender myself to 3D print.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

[image]

I know for the top 2 extruding parts that I'll need to be like the part of other battery covers that have that dip in the middle. As for the bottom 4 smaller extruding parts, I think they'll need some sort of hook on the ends.

How do I go about doing this?

Also, I tried looking for tutorials online to no avail. I saw some about modelling batteries, but not battery *covers*.

Comment: Please show your current work.  You may also see video tutorials on the website which has the name that rhymes with NooNube.  You might consider including a reference image, more specifics, and showing more effort in your question.  It is interesting how your question might be closed soon without explanation.  Perhaps its due to all the effort in whining and wailing occuring on meta. Its spreading like a virus ☀.

Comment: Sarcastic edits to the question don't help giving good answers. It does quite the opposite, I dare to say. Overall your topic is still _very_ specific, regarding the fact that Blender is a 3D modelling tool with quite a big variety of uses, which means that the part of the community who uses it for 3D printing is quite small compared to the people who use Blender for e.g. animation. Maybe Blender StackExchange just the wrong platform for the right question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your asking for some help adding the 3d parts of this model.

> I know for the top 2 extruding parts that I'll need to be like the part of other battery covers that have that dip in the middle. As for the bottom 4 smaller extruding parts, I think they'll need some sort of hook on the ends.

This can be done many ways. You may already be familiar with some of them. The most effective would probably be edit mode in blender. You should look into "proportional editing" and "boolean modifiers".

I would model the tabs as a 2d face side profile and extrude them. You could then use an array and boolean modifier to make the final mesh.